# Show the sample mean converges to minus infinity when ${X_n}$ are i.i.d. and $E(X_n^+)<\infty$ and $E(X_n{^-})=\infty$

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, expectation

Suppose ${X_n}$ are iid and $E(X_n^+)<\infty$ and $E(X_n{^-})=\infty$. Show that if $S_n := \sum_{j=1}^nX_n$ then $\frac{S_n}{n} \rightarrow -\infty$ almost surely.

A hint in my book says to use truncation so here is what I tried doing.

Since $E(X_n^+)<\infty$ then $E(X_n^+)=M$ where $M$ is some real number. Then $E(X_n^+1_{[|X_n|\le N]})=M$ for any $N\ge M$. Then since  $E(X_n{^-})=\infty$ there is going to exist some $N_0 \ge M$ such that for all $N \ge N_o \;$ we have that $E(X_n{^-}1_{[|X_n|\le N]})=N$

So for all $N \ge N_o$ we have that $\begin{align} \\  E(X_n{}1_{[|X_n|\le N]}) &= E(X_n{^+}1_{[|X_n|\le N]}) -E(X_n{^+}1_{[|X_n|\le N]}) 
\\ &= M - N \end{align}$

So be the strong law of large numbers $\dfrac{\sum_{j=1}^nX_n{}1_{[|X_n|\le N]}}{n} \rightarrow M-N$ almost surely. So as $N$ goes to infinity we get that $\dfrac{\sum_{j=1}^nX_n}{n} \rightarrow -\infty$ almost surely

Comment: You truncated the wrong way, you only want to truncate below, so that $\sum_{j=1}^n T_n/n \geq \sum_{j=1}^n X_n/n$ where $T_n$ is the truncation of $X_n$. Otherwise it looks fine.

Comment: @Ian Could you please expand on what you mean? I dont quite understand.

Comment: It is not so clear what the large $n$ behavior of $\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{X_n 1_{|X_n| \leq N}}{n}$ has to do with the large $n$ behavior of $\overline{X}$. But if you instead multiply by $1_{X_n \geq -N}$, then you have an inequality to work with, namely $X_n 1_{X_n \geq -N} \geq X_n$, to properly justify your last step.

Comment: @Ian So are we only truncating the negative part of $X_n $ above by $N $? And then the proof follows similar where we get that $E (X_n1_{[X_n > -N]})= M-N$?

Comment: Yes, I am suggesting that you just truncate the negative part and then perform the corresponding calculation.

Comment: Also, in your original work, it is not true that $E[X_n^+ 1_{|X_n| \leq N}]=M$ whenever $N \geq M$, indeed for many common distributions (exponential, normal, Poisson, ...) that is not true until you get to $N=\infty$.

Comment: @Ian I was worried about that, thanks for the input